# Deploying docker swarm without using docker machine

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, rhel, docker-swarm

Currently I have a bunch of `RHEL7 VMs` running on `RackSpace` and want to deploy docker swarm for testing purpose. The `Docker` Docs only describes the method to deploy docker swarm by using docker machine.

**Question:**
Since `VirtualBox` cannot be used in VMs, are any other ways such that I can directly deploy docker swarm on my VMs without using docker machine?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Still seeking for one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact Docker documentation offers you how to set up a swarm cluster 'manually' without using docker-machine: [Create a swarm for development](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/)

Answer (score 0):

[I think that this full step-by-step tutorial might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948).

It details how to deploy Swarm with a multi-hosts network, without Docker-machine by using consul and suggest two different means for the Swarm agent discovery (static file and token).