# Deploying docker swarm using bash script without docker-machine

Tags: bash, docker, virtual-machine, docker-swarm

Running `Ubuntu 18.04` on virtualmachines and want to install and deploy docker swarm "automatically" using bash script. (Almost like a one-click installation)

Referring to : [Deploying docker swarm without using docker machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668471/deploying-docker-swarm-without-using-docker-machine)

**Question:** how can I make this possible? Take bunch of manually commands and feed it into a bash script? How do I connect these VMs together in this swarm?

Comment: Did you consider using ansible instead of bash?
You could do it with scripts, but ansible seems more devoted to such a task since it will manage easilly the many ssh connections requested. And it will be a one-click install eventually!

Comment: I did consider ansible and puppet  instead of bash, but thought I would try only for the experience and comparison. If your experience says that ansible will leave me a lot of headaches I would be ever so greatful if you have any guide etc. to follow.

Comment: Ansible did not give me that many headache, though I was not the one writing the original scripts. If you already have some Ansible skills, I think it's a very well suited, and easy to maintain. I cannot provided the scripts I am using, but I can say they are very close to both ansible doc (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_swarm_module.html) and this tuto (https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/06/14/deploy-docker-swarm-using-ansible/)

Comment: are you assuming that VMs are already created or do you need the script to create them?

Comment: I have the VMs already made.