# The "--cluster-store" and "--cluster-advertise" don't work

Tags: docker

I try to setup docker cluster with `swarm` and `consul`. I have `manager`, `host1`, and `host2`.
I run `consul` and `swarm manager` containers on the manager.

```
$ docker run --rm -p 8500:8500 progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
$ docker run -d -p 2377:2375 swarm manage consul://<manager>:8500
```

On host1 and host2, I modify the daemon options with `--cluster-store` and `--cluster-advertise`, and restart `docker daemon`.

```
host1
DOCKER_OPTS="--cluster-store=consul://<manager>:8500 --cluster-advertise=<host1>:2375"
host2
DOCKER_OPTS="--cluster-store=consul://<manager>:8500 --cluster-advertise=<host2>:2375"
```

When I join host1 and host2 to the swarm, it fails.

```
host1 $ docker run --rm swarm join --advertise=<host1>:2375 consul://<manager>:8500
host2 $ docker run --rm swarm join --advertise=<host2>:2375 consul://<manager>:8500
```

From the swarm manager log, it error out.

```
time="2016-01-20T02:17:17Z" level=error msg="Get http://<host1>:2375/v1.15/info: dial tcp <host1>:2375: getsockopt: connection refused"
time="2016-01-20T02:17:20Z" level=error msg="Get http://<host2>:2375/v1.15/info: dial tcp <host2>:2375: getsockopt: connection refused"
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. and I followed this Link https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/

Answer (score 4):

Since i've come about a similar problem aswell i did eventually find out why it didn't work (in my example I'm using multiple boxes on a LAN `192.168.10.0/24` that I want to manage from in there and only allow access from the outside to certain containers -- the following examples are run on the box at `192.168.10.1`):

- set up the Daemons with `--cluster-store consul://192.168.10.1:8500` and port 8500 (deploying Consul & registrator on each Daemon as the first containers) and `--cluster-advertise 192.168.10.1:2375` aswell as `-H tcp://192.168.10.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375` (i do not however bind to the other available addresses as you would with `tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` and instead only bind to the local 192.168.10.0/24). **In case you want containers only binding to the local network aswell** (as i did in this case) you can specify the additional `--ip` parameter for the Daemon - when containers should be available to everywhere else aswell (in my case only an nginx load balancer with failover via keepalived) you specify binding the port to all interfaces `docker run ... -p 0.0.0.0:host_port:container_port ... <image>`
- Start the Daemons
- Deploy gliderlabs/registrator and Consul with compose (this is an example from the first box in my setup but I start the equivalent on all Daemons for a complete Consul HA failover setup) `docker-compose -p bootstrap up -d` (naming the containers `bootstrap_registrator_1` and `bootstrap_consul_1` in the private network `bootstrap`):

  ```
  version: '2'
  services:
    registrator:
      image: gliderlabs/registrator
      command: consul://192.168.10.1:8500
      depends_on:
        - consul
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
      restart: unless-stopped

    consul:
      image: consul
      command: agent -server -bootstrap -ui -advertise 192.168.10.1 -client 0.0.0.0
      hostname: srv-0
      network_mode: host
      ports:
        - "8300:8300"     # Server RPC, Server Use Only
        - "8301:8301/tcp" # Serf Gossip Protocol for LAN
        - "8301:8301/udp" # Serf Gossip Protocol for LAN
        - "8302:8302/tcp" # Serf Gossip Protocol for WAN, Server Use Only
        - "8302:8302/udp" # Serf Gossip Protocol for WAN, Server Use Only
        - "8400:8400"     # CLI RPC
        - "8500:8500"     # HTTP API & Web UI
        - "53:8600/tcp"   # DNS Interface
        - "53:8600/udp"   # DNS Interface
      restart: unless-stopped
  ```
- now the Daemons register and set locks on the KV-store (Consul) in `docker/nodes` and Swarm does not automatically seem to read from this location.. So when it tries to read which Daemons are available it doesn't find any. **Now this bit cost me the most time:**
  To solve this I had to specify `--discovery-opt kv.path=docker/nodes` and start Swarm with `docker-compose -p bootstrap up -d` - on all boxes aswell to end up with a Swarm HA failover of managers:

  ```
  version: '2'
  services:
    swarm-manager:
      image: swarm
      command: manage -H :3375 --replication --advertise 192.168.10.1:3375 --discovery-opt kv.path=docker/nodes consul://192.168.10.1:8500
      hostname: srv-0
      ports:
        - "192.168.10.1:3375:3375" #
      restart: unless-stopped
  ```
- Now I end up with a working Swarm that is only available on the `192.168.10.0/24` network on port 3375. All containers that are started are only available to this network aswell unless i specify `-p 0.0.0.0:host_port:container_port` when starting (with `docker run`)
- Further scaling: When I add more boxes to the local network to grow the capacity my idea would be to add more Daemons and maybe non-manager Swarm instances with those aswell as later Consul clients (rather than servers, started with `-server`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running consul for the multihosts-networking discovery or for the Swarm agents discovery?

Did you try to check the `consul members` ?
Why don't you run `docker daemon` to connect **locally** to `consul` and then `consul join` the consul members ? Is there any reason for not doing so?

I also suggest the static file methods for Swarm agents discovery. Fastest, easiest and safest mean I know!

You should take a look at: [how to create docker overlay network between multi hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948) it may help you.

Comment: I want to try the `key-value server` mode. What is the difference of static file and `key-value server`?

Comment: As your guide, the opt is `/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --cluster-advertise eth0:2375 --cluster-store consul://127.0.0.1:8500`. Why set `--cluster-store consul://127.0.0.1:8500`? I set `--cluster-store consul://<consul IP>:8500`, and the docker daemon fail to start.

Comment: `consul` is distributed. Each daemon advertise itself locally to consul and the consul master joins the nodes (and thus the docker daemon). I set it locally so if there is any flaw in the network, the daemon won't be impacted by it.
It works well.
The difference between key-value store and static file is that the static file requires nothing but a file. The network is not used for the agent discovery, it's the safest, easiest and fastest as it does not use anything else than just a file on the Swarm master. No client/server nor distributed application needed.

Comment: @Auzias Your guide relies on hub discovery which is affected by warning given here: https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/#docker-hub-as-a-hosted-discovery-service ... in my case I was thus setting up consul registry for discovery, thus it needs to be running prior to any swarm and therefore was designed to run separately.

In my case I failed to use that same consul cluster for storing k/v to establish overlay network. See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20996 ... the consul cluster is requiring auth token. at firelyu: Is this similar to your case?

Comment: Nope, I do not use hub discovery. I detail the steps to use it, but I also suggest, and advise, to use the static-file discovery. This is for swarm agent discovery, as for container discovery (needed to enable multi-hosts network) I use consul.

Comment: @Auzias I followed your instruction , but still I cannot fix the issue. now it start the docker daemon. :(

Comment: What is your issue? What does start the docker daemon?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove "docker.pid" and "docker.sock" at /var/run. Next, restart your host-machine and restart service docker by "sudo service docker restart"

Good luck to you !!