# Need Explanation for the docker documentation on the swarm

Tags: docker, consul, docker-swarm

I finished this documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-w-machine/

It works fine.

Now I tried to setup this EC2 instances by following this documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/

I am in Step 4. Set up a discovery backend

I cannot understand the steps what I need to do further.

I created 5 nodes in EC2: manager0, manager1, consul0, node0, node1. Now I need to know how to setup service discovery with swarm.

In that document they ask us to connect manager0 and consul0 then ifconfig, then they given as etc0 instance. I don't know where this is coming from.

Ultimately I need to know where (in which node?) to run this command:

`$ docker run -d -p 8500:8500 --name=consul progrium/consul -server -bootstrap`

Any suggestion for me How to clear this step?

Comment: What specific question do you have for Step 4 of the tutorial?

Comment: I created 5 nodes in EC2 , manager0,manager1,consul0,node0,node1. now , I need to know how to setup service discovery with swarm. In that document they ask us to connect manger0 and consul0 then ifconfig ,  then they given as etc0 instance . dont know where that coming from. ultimatly I need to know where (in which node?) to run this command 
$ docker run -d -p 8500:8500 --name=consul progrium/consul -server -bootstrap

Comment: That's the information you should put in your original question, so people with the same experience can help answer.

Comment: thank you @warmoverflow, I will follow this from my next questions, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: prakash, you can click the "Edit" link under your question and add the information yourself :-)

Comment: @CindyMeister did, thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34434948/5321002) should help you

Answer (score 0):

Consul will run on the consul0 server you created.  So basically you first need to be able to run docker on worker0 and worker1 remotely, this is step 3.  A better way of doing this is editing the daemon directly with the command:

```
sudo echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"' > /etc/default/docker`
```

Then restart docker.  Afterwards you will find that you can run docker remotely from master0, master1 or any other instance behind your firewall with docker commands that start with:

```
docker -H $WORKER0_IPADDRESS:2375
```

For example if your workers ip address was 1.2.3.4 this would run the docker ps command remotely:

```
docker -H 1.2.3.4:2375 ps
```

This is what swarm runs on.  Then start up your consul server with the command you want to run, you got that one right and thats it you wont do anything else with the consul0 server except use its IP address when you run your swarm commands.

So if $CONSUL0 represented the IP address of your consul server this is how you would set up the rest of swarm.  If you ran each of them on the local machine of each node:

On consul0:

```
docker run -d -p 8500:8500 --restart=unless-stopped --name=consul progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
```

On master0 and master1:

```
docker run --name=master -d -p 4000:4000 swarm manage -H :4000 --replication --advertise $(hostname -i):4000 consul://$CONSUL0:8500
```

On worker0 and worker1:

```
docker run -d --name=worker swarm join --advertise=$(hostname -i):2375 consul://$CONSUL0:8500/
```