# Can I have one Docker Swarm Manager and different clusters?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I've just re-looked at Docker Swarm and I was wondering if it is possible to have one central Swarm manager and have it manage `n` Swarm agent clusters.

**Use Case**:

Consider a service (call it DockerServ) that allows people to build their own docker clusters. DockerServ will have a single Swarm Manager that can spin up containers in different clusters.

**Questions**:

- Is this possible or there **has** to be a Swarm Manager in each cluster.
- Will I be able to see contaiers in all clusters from a node inside one of the clusters (considering clusters may belong to different people that have SSH access to nodes in their clusters)?
- Will this present any security issues (assuming that each cluster at DockerServ has a different owner?)

**Conclusion**

If this is a totally wrong approach, what would be the best way to implement this? Any resources will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "different clusters"? Do you want to use a cluster of clusters? You can find a whole step-by-step tutorial to [deploy a Swarm on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948).

Comment: @Auzias please see the graphic I added above.

Comment: As long as your Swarm Docker Agent can offer a socket accessible from outside (NAT-ed/PAT-ed) then there is no issue to deploy this. So the answer is: yes.

Comment: If it possible: where is the documentation for this use case?