# How to access Consul used in Docker overlay networks?

Tags: docker, consul

I do have set the overlay multi-host network that uses Consul, without Swarm.

I want to access Consul for my own needs. When I run my docker infrastructure locally (on several docker machines), I can't reach it with:

```
consul members --rpc-addr=192.168.99.100:8500
```

This does not return anything. Port `8500` is the only exposed. I see `8300` (and bunch of other ports) is also open, but not exposed.

Should I expose 8300? Why Docker/VMs are using 8500?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ports used by `consul`.

- `8500` is used to communicate with other consul agent.
- `8400` is used to perform RPC with the consul agent bound to the ip address specified with the option `-bind` (local by default).

Hence the command:

```
consul agent -data-dir /tmp/consul -node=$HOSTNAME -bind=$IP
```

This would start a consul agent, named `$HOSTNAME` and bound to the IP address `$IP`, to which commands can be sent by commands such as `consul members -rpc-addr=$IP:8400`.

---

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948) useful. It describes a step-by-step tutorial to run an multi-host overlay network with Swarm using Consul.

---

#### Edit

As pointed out by [@vince-bowdren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174843/vince-bowdren), the documentation give [in depth details on the various udp/tcp ports used by consul](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#ports).

Comment: There are six different ports used by Consul, some of them over udp as well as tcp. See the [docs for the full list](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#ports)