# How to create an overlay network with Docker?

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

When I try to create an overlay network with Docker I get the following error:

```
docker@boot2docker:/vagrant$ docker network create --driver overlay somenetwork

Error response from daemon: failed to parse pool request for address space 
"GlobalDefault" pool "" subpool "": cannot find address space GlobalDefault 
(most likely the backing datastore is not configured)`
```

I found this bug report on GitHub: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18770

I checked my Boot2Docker image, it is using sysvinit and not systemd, so this shouldn't be a problem, and also the kernel version seems to be good:

```
docker@boot2docker:/vagrant$ uname -r
4.1.19-boot2docker
```

Is it possible that this is a misuse of the overlay network concept that I try to run this only on one host...? Maybe this causes that strange error?

**Update:**
I think this was a mistake to execute the network creation command to the locally running docker daemon. I think I should have done this to my swarm manager instead - in this case the error message is different:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:3375 network create --driver overlay network
Error response from daemon: No healthy node available in the cluster
```

When I check the status of the swarm cluster there are no nodes indeed. Maybe the original problem is my swarm join command was not fully correct...?

```
docker run -d swarm join consul://127.0.0.1:8500/
```

Comment: Could you show the output of "ps aux | grep docker" please. More specifically: what are the options with wich the daemon is started?

Comment: Hi Auzias, I've already checked that. cluster-store and cluster options were included: --cluster-store consul://127.0.0.1:8500 --cluster eth0:2375
Check my update. :)

Comment: Are you sure the `--cluster` option is correct? Shouldn't it be `--cluster-advertise`?

Comment: That error message is specifically what you get if the *--cluster-store* and *--cluster-advertise* options are not configured in the docker daemon. You can check; run *docker info*, and those two options will be listed if the docker daemon knows about them. If not, you haven't successfully set these options.

Answer (score 1):

If you read through the [documentation on overlay networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#an-overlay-network), you see that in order to create an overlay network you first need to configure a key/value store (Docker currently supports etcd, consul, and zookeeper) that Docker uses to coordinate things between multiple hosts.

From the docs:

> To create an overlay network, you configure options on the daemon on each Docker Engine for use with overlay network. There are three options to set:
>   Option    Description
>
> - `--cluster-store=PROVIDER://URL`
>
>   Describes the location of the KV service.
> - `--cluster-advertise=HOST_IP|HOST_IFACE:PORT`
>
>   The IP address or interface of the HOST used for clustering.
> - `--cluster-store-opt=KEY-VALUE OPTIONS`
>
>   Options such as TLS certificate or tuning discovery Timers

From your question, it doesn't sound like you have performed the necessary configuration.

Comment: I use Consul as a kv store, but maybe I misconfigured something... Actually, I try to create a swarm "cluster" but only on one host. I used [these](http://pastebin.com/8zfSh97V) commands to setup the infrastructure.

Comment: This also doesn't pay credence to what to do when you first are trying to run a consul cluster in swarm mode in order to support same or other swarms which rely on said consul cluster

Answer (score 0):

As the update suggested ..

#### .. the problem is ..

your swarm join command.

#### A solution could be ..

```
docker run swarm join --addr=192.168.196.16:2375 token://`cat swarm_id`
```

Assuming that you created the swarm using a token. As for me I rather use static file.

You'll find everything you need in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948).

Comment: token? :)) wait...this is new for me. :) The example tutorial what I followed didn't use this parameter...strange. Thanks for the link, I'll check it!

Comment: ah okay...tokens are for the hosted discovery service. no, I don't use that. I'd like to use Consul instead.

Comment: What does `consul members` output?