# Do I really need docker swarm?

Tags: docker, load-balancing, docker-swarm

I have a silly question regarding docker swarm.
I am thinking I can start a web application image in two containers, either in same server or two vm servers, then I start a load balance container, pointing to two web app containers through IP and port. 
In this case, why do I need docker swarm for clustering management? What benefits can docker swarm bring? 
I have read from docker documentation, they only introduce what is swarm and how to use swarm. But I can not find out answer for why I have to use swarm.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using several Docker hosts?

Comment: @Auzias, Yes, If I run one images in two docker container or more, these docker containers will be located in separate vms, do you see any value to use swarm to manage these containers (or nodes)? Or just let nginx LB to distribute traffic directly?

Comment: Swarm has nothing to do with nginx. That's two really different tools! One cannot replace the services the other offer. Swarm will ease your deployment if you want to abstract your Docker hosts as if it were one sole Docker host.

Comment: @Auzias, that is also what I don't really know. So, if I start two nodes, and deployed same images into the two nodes, join the two nodes to swarm and let swarm manage it. Then, 1) what is swarming managing? can swarm auto-start the container if the container died? 2) Can swarm auto-create more nodes if the resource is not enough? Which mean, if traffic grows fast, do we still manually create more node and deploy more containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **What is swarming managing?** [turns a pool of Docker hosts into a single, virtual Docker host](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/overview/).
2. **Can swarm auto-start the container if the container died?** Yes it can, so can the Docker daemon on each host.
3. **Can swarm auto-create more nodes if the resource is not enough?** No it cannot. It does not aims on providing this service. Nevertheless you can program a node that start and run containers when needed.
4. **Which mean, if traffic grows fast, do we still manually create more node and deploy more containers?** Yes, unfortunately.

---

**update**
If needed, [here is an answer that details how to deploy a Swarm cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948).

Comment: Great clarification. I have heard kubernetes is also providing similar service as Swarm, do you know if kubernetes can meet above requirements?

Comment: No, I do not. I have no experience with kubernetes. If my post answers your question I suggest you to tag it as a response so your question is then tagged as answered ;)