# Docker and Consul by example: need clarification

Tags: docker, consul

I'm learning Docker-Swarm with Consul and found some issues I don't really understand. Basically, I created a Docker-Swarm cluster (node-01 and node-02) with Consul Sevice Discovery. I then run a multi-container application (Express app with Mongo) and I can see it is running on node-02. In order to run it, I have to go in and find the IP address of my node-02 and then open the browser.

It works fine, it's just that I was expecting that I could just go to some virtual IP (or DNS) and that it the Consul service (or Swarm) would then translate it to the correct IP address of node-02 in this example.

Next item is that when I log into Consul web UI, I was expecting to see the nodes under the 'nodes' menu, but that seems not to be the case. I was also expecting to get an overview of the 'applications' or 'services' I was running on the node-01 and node-02, but that is also not the case.

My questions are:

1. Can someone explain why I would need to manually find out on which node in the cluster my app is running. Cannot imagine this is done in larger deployments.
2. Can someone address why I don't see the 'nodes' and 'services' in the Consul UI?

Note: I tried to be as short as possible though I have been documenting the full setup in a blog post (with screenshots) for those who want to see more details. [Go to blog post](http://www.wapptastic.com/docker-run-applications-on-docker-swarm-cluster-part-2/)

Comment: May I suggest you to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948)? -- didn't take the time to read your question though, just the title

Comment: Thanks, it does not really address the two specific questions I have though.

Comment: Does my answer, here below, lack details or not answer?

Comment: I setup a reverse proxy and that worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Question 1

> I would like to access the service without having to use the Swarm agent's IP address

#### Solution

It is feasible, you just need to start up a *[reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)* such as [nginx](http://nginx.com/) in a container ([here are the official nginx images](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)). At the start up of this container use the option `--link` with the name of the application. Thus the IP address of this container will added in the file `/etc/hosts` of the reverse proxy container (remember to use `--name` and `--hostname`). Run this reverse proxy container on a specific node.
**So the solution to get rid of the IP address issue is to deploy another container on a specific node (and then specific IP address)?** Yes! But using `--link` will make this issue scalable ;)

#### Question 2

> I was expecting to see the nodes under the 'nodes' menu, but that **seems** not to be the case.

What you do mean? What did you expect? Do you need to query the k,v-storage DB?

Answer (score 2):

Check this: https://github.com/vmudigal/microservices-sample

```
                     Microservices Sample Architecture
```

[image]