# Is docker swarm manager part of the swarm cluster?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I don't quite understand why the official documents are using so many machines to create a swarm cluster. Is it possible to hv consul and swarm manager in the same machine ? Also, is swarm manager part of the cluster ? If, say, I create an overlay network, is swarm manager host part of that network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. The Swarm Manager is not part of the network overlay. More generally Swarm is just a container running on a Docker daemon. If you add this Docker daemon into the cluster, then the Swarm Manager hosting the Swarm container will also be a Swarm Agent and then receive containers.

If you ever need, you can find a whole step-by-step tutorial on [how to deploy a Swarm cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948).

Comment: Thank you :D Another question, can I have different swarm clusters sharing the same consul backend? It seems like the data in consul doesn't give the swarm cluster an id...

Comment: I don't get your answer, can you rephrase it please?

Comment: I'd like to build two swarm clusters, one for testing and another for production. could these two clusters share the same discovery backend(consul in my case)?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but I would test it extensively before trusting it. I would advise it in anyways though.