# OSI Layer Model for Docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In the ever expanding Docker ecosystem has anyone seen a 7-layer OSI Reference Model-like diagram putting the pieces together?

Where would Docker be?  Swarm/Kubernetes (and other alternatives [Shipyard, Fleet])?  Fabric8?

If there isn't an existing reference, anyone care to take a stab at one?

Comment: My guess would be that it depends on the situation. Use the `--net=host` and you get the usual 7-layers model. Deploy an app over Swarm with [multi-host networking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948) and you get a 7+ layered model as the network is _virtualized_.