# Docker Swarm - strategy doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have provisioned a swarm master and swarm nodes with Docker Machine (as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/provision-with-machine/)). Everything is working fine; all the machines are created and running, they have all been discovered and accepts containers.

The output from 'docker-machine ls' is:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME         ACTIVE      DRIVER         STATE     URL                          SWARM               DOCKER    ERRORS
default      -           virtualbox     Stopped                                                    Unknown   
local        -           virtualbox     Stopped                                                    Unknown   
my-swarm     * (swarm)   digitalocean   Running   tcp://104.131.161.197:2376   my-swarm (master)   v1.11.1   
node0        -           digitalocean   Running   tcp://104.236.29.169:2376    my-swarm            v1.11.1   
node1        -           digitalocean   Running   tcp://104.236.216.164:2376   my-swarm            v1.11.1
```

The problem I'm having is with the distribution of containers. No matter which strategy I set for the swarm, it only seems to distribute containers to one of the nodes at a time. I.e. I run a bunch of containers, and the are all started on the same node, as shown below (with strategy Spread):

```
$ docker ps
5c075d7ccddc        stress              "/bin/sh -c /stress.s"   32 seconds ago       Up 31 seconds                           node0/elated_goldstine
5bae22a15829        stress              "/bin/sh -c /stress.s"   46 seconds ago       Up 44 seconds                           node0/cocky_booth
dc52b3dfa0e6        stress              "/bin/sh -c /stress.s"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       node0/goofy_kalam
3b9e69c694da        stress              "/bin/sh -c /stress.s"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       node0/focused_fermat
ef0e006ff3e0        stress              "/bin/sh -c /stress.s"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       node0/stoic_engelbart
53e46b19ab33        stress              "/bin/sh -c /stress.s"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       node0/condescending_rosalind
e9e126c7f4c6        stress              "/bin/sh -c /stress.s"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       node0/sleepy_jang
f9c0003d509d        stress              "/bin/sh -c /stress.s"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       node0/amazing_bhaskara
```

What I would expect here is for the containers to be distributed roughly evenly on the 3 nodes, especially as the script I'm running in the containers is designed to take as much CPU as possible. But instead all of them are on node0 (which I would only expect with Binpack). The Random strategy has the exact same behaviour.

The output from 'docker info' with the swarm master set as active seems correct:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 15
 Running: 4
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 11
Images: 5
Server Version: swarm/1.2.1
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, containerslots, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 3 
 my-swarm: 104.131.161.197:2376
  └ ID: L2HK:F6S3:WWIM:BHNI:M4XL:KLEA:4U22:J6CE:ZHZI:OGGT:76KF:MTQU
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 2
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 513.4 MiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=, kernelversion=4.2.0-27-generic, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 15.10, provider=digitalocean, storagedriver=aufs
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-05-09T10:25:24Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.11.1
 node0: 104.236.29.169:2376
  └ ID: I3TQ:5BMS:TM2P:GLL4:64OH:BDMY:SWBU:3QG4:TOZ2:LEDW:A6SQ:X34H
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 12
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 513.4 MiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=, kernelversion=4.2.0-27-generic, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 15.10, provider=digitalocean, storagedriver=aufs
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-05-09T10:25:02Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.11.1
 node1: 104.236.216.164:2376
  └ ID: OTQH:UBSV:2HKE:ZVHL:2K7Z:BYGC:ZX25:Y6BQ:BN5J:UWEB:65KE:DABM
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 1
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 513.4 MiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=, kernelversion=4.2.0-27-generic, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 15.10, provider=digitalocean, storagedriver=aufs
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-05-09T10:25:10Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.11.1
Plugins: 
 Volume: 
 Network: 
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-27-generic
Operating System: linux
Architecture: amd64
CPUs: 3
Total Memory: 1.504 GiB
Name: my-swarm
Docker Root Dir: 
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
```

Is there some piece I have missed that is necessary for this type of automatic distribution to work the way I'm expecting?

Comment: Did you make sure all your Docker Agent have the image you try to run locally? (note that `swarm pull` or `swarm build` may not work as you expect it to)

Comment: @Auzias Aha, that must be it, thanks a lot. Makes perfect sense, the swarm manager just sends the command, not the container itself. This makes Swarm standalone a lot less practical though. Is there a better way to do this than to manually do eval "$(...)" and building? I guess I need to look into something like UCP?

Comment: Tested it, seems to work as expected now. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue

It is most likely that you Docker Agent does not have the image you try to run on them.

Note that `swarm build` and `swarm pull` will not `build`, or `pull`, on each Docker agent.

#### Solution A

Run the `pull` manually on each Docker Agent

#### Solution B *(not tested)*

Run a local [Docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) wherein the Docker agent will pull the images from.

---

Have fun with Swarm! Also, if I may, I suggest you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948) that details a whole step-by-step tutorial on Swarm.