# Should Swarm Master Join As Node in a Single Node Cluster?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

We are building a small cluster, and a (strange) requirement is to setup everything in one machine, to which other machines can join in the future.

I set up consul with:

```
docker run -d -p 8500:8500 --name=consul progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
```

and the master with:

```
docker run -d -p 4000:4000 swarm manage -H :4000 --advertise <ip_here>:4000 consul://<ip_here>:8500
```

where docker is run with:

```
sudo docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

and `docker -H :4000 info` lists the Nodes as 0 at this stage, where I cannot run any images with `docker -H :4000 run <image>` because `No healthy node available in the cluster.`

When I join the master node to the cluster with:

```
docker run -d swarm join --advertise=<ip_here>:2375 consul://<ip_here>:8500
```

Then `docker -H :4000 info` lists the Nodes as 1, and I can run containers.

Please note that `<ip_here>` refers all to the same ip of the machine.

Is this the intended behaviour? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing Docker Machine's way of creating a Swarm cluster, as well as using Swarm that is integrated into Docker v1.12.0, I wanted to post an update. Swarm master does join Swarm cluster, by running two containers, an agent and a master.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I use the Swarm Master as the Consul server. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948) may help you. Then, to answer, the Swarm Master does not join in as a single node cluster.

You can't deploy Swarm on a single node. That's not its use and cannot work that way. Swarm *[turns a pool of Docker hosts into a single, virtual Docker host](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/overview/)*, so if the pool of Docker hosts contains zero hosts... There is no Docker Agent to host container.

Comment: My question is more of why can't I run containers on Swarm master without joining it to the cluster, as the nodes are seen as 0.

Comment: What do you mean "the nodes are seen as 0" ? How many Swarm Agent do you have?

Comment: I meant the node number. The Swarm master shows the number of nodes as 0. And I cannot deploy a container since `No healthy node available in the cluster`. I run swarm on only 1 node, which is the master.

Comment: You can't deploy Swarm on a single node. That's not its use and cannot work that way. [_Swarm turns a pool of Docker hosts into a single, virtual Docker host_](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/overview/), so if the _pool of Docker hosts_ contains zero hosts... There is no Docker Agent to host container.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. So when I join a new node (one master-with consul- and one joined node), I see Node number as 1, not 2, am I right?

Comment: Yes that's it. Can you show me the command you execute to start Swarm please? [You'll get a detailed step-by-step tutorial to deploy Swarm on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948)

Comment: The commands I use in my question are the exact commands, as for <ip_here>, I use my local network ip, such as 192.168.0.XX. They are taken from Swarm's official guide to deploy a cluster for production. Could you edit your answer to include what you wrote in your last two comments, so that I can accept, since that was what I was looking for?

Comment: Edited. You could copy/paste the command line that is executed to start Swarm please? I'll like to see it and try to correct it, there might be an error.

Comment: It is bare metal running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I run the following commands directly from the shell. First I `deploy docker run -d -p 8500:8500 --name=consul progrium/consul -server -bootstrap` to start consul, then `docker run -d -p 4000:4000 swarm manage -H :4000 --advertise 192.168.0.13:4000 consul://192.168.0.13:8500` to start swarm master. Then `docker -H :4000 info` lists the node number as 0.

Comment: You are right, there are a few more points that I might be missing when following the official guide. But the answer above installs consul as a service instead of a container, which I would not prefer.

Comment: In any case, that answer also lists the node number excluding the swarm master, so for swarm, at least two machines, one master and one node are needed. Thanks!