# Overlay network on Swarm Mode without Docker Machine

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I currently have three hosts (`docker1`, `docker2` and `docker3`) which I have *not* set up using Docker Machine, each one running the v1.12-rc4 Docker daemon.

I run `docker swarm init` on `docker1`, which in turn prints a `docker swarm join` command which I run on both `docker2` and `docker3`. At that point, running `docker info` on each host contains the `Swarm: active` line.

It is at this point that the behavior seems to differ from what I used to get with the standalone Swarm container. Especially, running `docker network ls` will only show me the networks on the local host, and when trying to create an overlay network, it does not seem like worker nodes are aware of it (*i.e.* it does not show up on their `docker network ls`.)

I feel like I have missed out on some important information relating to the workings of the Swarm Mode as opposed to the Swarm container.

What is the correct way of setting up such a cluster *without* Docker Machine on Docker 1.12 while getting the overlay network feature?

Answer (score 1):

I too thought this was an issue when I first started using it.

This works a little differently in 1.12rc4 - when you deploy a container to your swarm with that network attached to it, it should then create the network on the other nodes as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

You are using the `docker` command (used to communicate with your *localhost Docker daemon*) and not the "`swarm`" command (used to communicate with the Swarm master).

#### Solution

It depends on the command you used to start Swarm.
A full step-by-step tutorial (including details on how to deploy an overlay network) is detailled on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948). I'm sure that reading this will help you ;)

Comment: I had already visited the link you provided. While it works, it does not solve my issue of using the Swarm mode introduced with version 1.12. Or have I misunderstood the feature completely?

Comment: Swarm can be seen as a Docker daemon. Using the command `docker` communicate with UNIX socket (by default) with the local Docker daemon. You cannot create a swarm overlay network with this command as far as I know. Could you add the link, in the question, of the process you follow please.

Answer (score 0):

With a network scope of swarm, the network is only propagated to worker nodes on an as-needed basis. If you create a service using that network, and it gets scheduled on that worker node, the network will show up in the `docker network ls`.

With the now-upcoming 1.13 release, you can get a network that has similar behavior to the non-swarm networks by doing `docker network create --attachable ...`. That network will be valid for both services and normal containers, and will be available to all members of the cluster. As of 1.13.0-rc2, those don't seem to show up in the output of `docker network ls`.