# Docker swarm, Consul and Spring Boot

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, orchestration

I have 6 microservices packed in docker containers. On every swarm node, i have installed consul agent, binded to host ip, and client in 0.0.0.0 mode.
All microservices are in docker-compose file which I am running from Swarm manager. 
Microservices are written in Java and in bootstrap.yml I must to specify consul agent endpoint. Possible choices are:

- localhost
- ${HOSTIP} environment variable

Problems:
 - localhost is not localhost of host, but container localhost, and I don't have consul agent on container localhost but host.
 - ${HOSTIP} in compose file i have to supply this env var. But, I don't know where Swarm MAnager will schedule microservice start so I cannot know which IP address will be used.

I tried to expose on each node host ip address but since i am running compose from manager, it will not read this variable.

Do you have any proposal how to solve this? I have consul cluster, 3 managers and 3 nodes. on each manager and node i have consul agent started (as docker container). No matter what type of networking i am using, i am not able to start up microservice. I started consul as --net=host and --net=bridge, but this is not working.

Is there anyone with some idea?
Thanks ahead.

Comment: [This reading](http://blog.nimbleci.com/2016/08/17/how-to-set-up-and-deploy-to-a-1000-node-docker-swarm/) may help you. [This one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365604/how-to-create-docker-overlay-network-between-multi-hosts/34434948#34434948).

Comment: Checkout the new Docker Engine swarm feature in v1.12. Service discovery is now built in, meaning you may not require the use of consul anymore to track container instances. https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/. I can also recommend the following which details how to integrate load balancers with the new swarm mode: https://technologyconversations.com/2016/08/01/integrating-proxy-with-docker-swarm-tour-around-docker-1-12-series/

Answer (score 0):

So you are running consul in containers also, right? Is it possible in your setup to link containers? So you could start the consul containers as "consul" on each host and link your microservices to it. Linked containers get a hosts entry and so the consul service should be reachable at "consul:8500" from within your services.
Edit: If you are using the official Consul Docker image from Hashicorp, you can configure the client address to 0.0.0.0, this should make the consul API available to the other containers running on the host.

Comment: I am running consul in docker container, official image on all hosts. client address is set to 0.0.0.0. also, i am running consul with flag --net=host. in compose file, there is 5 containers. links won't help because consul is on host network but containers are started in overlay network. i've tried also with bridge networking but it wasn't working.

Comment: True, linking and --net=host simultaneously is not allowed. With the official image from Hashicorp you can use some environment variables. This variant worked for me: `docker run -d -e CONSUL_CLIENT_INTERFACE=docker0 -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=lo --net=host consul agent` - This binds the client interface and API to the Docker bridge interface (standard is 172.17.0.1 as of now) and I was able to call the agent via curl from another container via this IP

Comment: Simply doesnt' work. Consul is started on localhost but since java application is in container and consul endopoint is localhost, it just doesn't doesn't know to use localhost from VM, not from container.

Comment: When run like in my example, the consul endpoint in the other container would bei `172.17.0.1:8500` not `localhost` as the consul client interface binds to the docker bridge interface. It works exactly like this in my setup.

Comment: Ok, i've put 172.17.0.1:8500 as connection string in bootstrap.yml and service is finding consul now. The health check is failing now.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own Q: This is not a way we want to do this, I mean, we cannot put some things in Swarm and some thing outside Swarm with expectation that it will work. It will not. Consul as a service discovery cannot be used outside Swarm, too. Simple answer would be to use Docker Orchestration and Service discovery and not to involve Consul. If someone is using Swarm, everything should be in overlay networks (rabbit, redis, elk and so on)...

Comment: When you say "This is not a way we want to do this", are you talking about what the OP asks or what kgorskowski said in his answer? Could you please [edit] your answer and clarify it? Thank you!